# How can i insert rows from another table in firebird?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, vb.net, firebird

OK, so i have a fire bird database with 2 tables, table a and table b, some of their columns are different but some are the same, in VB.net how can i load data from table a into table b but only the columns that are the same?

Essentially table a has the complete data where table b houses a scaled down version of the data that will be shown to the user in the UI, as an overview in a ListView so that when they double click it in ListView a window pops up with all the data in table a.

Also i simplified the above examples, my main goal is to have table b have all the common data from multiple other tables like, table a, table c, table d etc.

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Edit:
Sorry forgot to add that this is going to be in a multi user environment with at a minimum of 6 active users at any given time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use `insert . . . select`:

```
insert into tableb(col1, . . . coln)
    select col1, . . . coln
    from table a;
```

However, why not just use a query for the `ListView` or a view:

```
create view tableb as
    select col1, . . . coln
    from tablea;
```

Comment: I could just do the query, but wouldn't that be slower as every time the program was reopened wouldn't it have to re-read the entire table a again? I should have also put in the post that this is for a multi user environment with at least 6 active users at any given time

Comment: @user1090660 To be honest, 6 users is nothing. A view is preferable over a separate table (think of keeping the data fresh) and it won't have a significant performance impact over querying a separate table.

Comment: OK, what is a view, i never used that sql command before. and how can i scale it to use multiple other tables?

Comment: @user1090660 A view is a virtual table. You define it with an SQL query, and then you can query it as if it is a normal table.

Comment: ok, is it built into the database, i.e. i only have to run the create command once or does it have to be done each time? the reason i ask is because i am using firebird maestro to design the actual database itself so that less is handled in code, so if it only is run once then i can add it in using firebird maestro?

Comment: The create command for the view only has to be called once.  The database stores the view.

Comment: @user1090660 See http://www.ibphoenix.com/files/60sqlref.html#RSf20247 (and http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-ddl-view.html )